# How to approach this project?

Tags: jquery, slider, accordion

I've been recently learning jQuery, and while I can accomplish most of the things I want to do, I aknowledge I'm probably wasting lines and lines of code and overcomplicating updates, I guess that's part of the self teaching proccess since it has happened to me for everything I've learned by myself, with time I get to optimize my work, but at first I create ugly stuff and waste lots of time.

The thing is I'm not asking for code snippets here, I think I can figure that out myself and I want to, as a step of my learning proccess, I just want to know how to approach this little project I have in mind so I can start to build a jQuery coder mindset.

I have a 100% screen width wrapper, inside that wrapper, the slider with overflow hidden, and then inside the slider there are many 250*150 boxes.

Whenever you click on each of those boxes, it will open showing content and closing the previously opened box, pretty much like an accordion system with a little twist.

The twist being that open boxes will always be on the left=250px position, so, if you click on box 3, it would move the slider to left:-500px.

Now, I can do that, but the problem is that the way I'd do it, it would be a nightmare to update, so the question here is: How would you approach this project?

Would you create some variables first I assume? Perhaps one to identify wether it's closed or open? Number each div so you could multiply it by 250 when animating the left position? Using child selectors and what not?

Hopefully someone can help me here, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would get it working using [CSS3 only](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/cssplay-horizontal-accordian.html), then use jQuery to emulate CSS3 in older browsers. jQuery is not always necessary in modern browsers, especially if the content can be hidden by default in the markup using CSS rather generated from a JavaScript data structure.